# Adding an absolute path to an OpenAPI YAML file

Tags: yaml, openapi

I'm trying to put the `getBaseDir` function from PHP in my OpenAPI YAML file to get the absolute path, but I don't know how to do it.

```yaml
   responses:
     '200':
       description: successful Operation
       content:
         application/json:
           schema:
             $ref: 'var/www/docroot/www/app/code/local/Project/Myproject/OpenAPI/components/schemas/test.yaml'
```

Comment: Can you share more details, like the code involved?

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given configuration? How is this related to the `getBaseDir` function?